# Query for getting all data in a particular timeframe for the respective agent_id

Tags: mysql, query

Currently I'm using CodeIgniter and MySQL to retrieve a count of data within a particular timeframe. My table data looks something like this:

[image]

Where there are different agents who are changing statuses in a particular timeframe. So what I want is to layout all the agents in the table and display what status change they had made in a particular timeframe. To get a count of all the data in a particular timeframe I used this following query which works:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status_to = 'Draft' THEN 1 END) AS draft, SUM(CASE WHEN status_to = 'Unpublish' THEN 1 END) AS unpublish, SUM(CASE WHEN status_to = 'Publish' THEN 1 END) AS publish, SUM(CASE WHEN status_to = 'Action' THEN 1 END) AS action, SUM(CASE WHEN status_to = 'Unlisted' THEN 1 END) AS unlisted, SUM(CASE WHEN status_to = 'Sold' THEN 1 END) AS sold, SUM(CASE WHEN status_to = 'Let' THEN 1 END) AS let FROM `crm_logs` WHERE cast(logtime as date) BETWEEN "2021-09-25" AND "2021-10-01"
```

But now I want it so that it is grouped by the agent_is, and the respective agent_id has the status next to him.

Comment: Does adding `GROUP BY agent_id` not work in your query? Do you get an error message? Can you provide an example of what the output should look like?

Comment: Why is `logtime` being cast to `date`? Note `SUM(CASE WHEN status_to = 'Draft' THEN 1 END)` is equivalent to `SUM(status_to = 'Draft')`.